# Google Maps Generated by Advance Custom Fields in Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, advanced-custom-fields

I have read a number of SO questions related to showing Google maps within jQuery tabs. I understand that the map must be initialized or redrawn after the tab is active and have tried many solutions from SO but none seem to work for my particular case.

I am using Bootstrap 3 tabs, and the maps are generated in a repeater using the Google Maps custom field from Advance Custom Fields. There are multiple maps within a tab.

Here is the code that is on the tab page

```
<?php if( have_rows('info_accomm') ): ?>
<?php while( have_rows('info_accomm') ): the_row(); ?>

    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
       <?php 
            $location = get_sub_field('google_map');
            if( !empty($location) ):
        ?>

        <div class="acf-map">
            <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>"></div>
        </div>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The JS used is the default from the Advance Custom Fields site: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/

I was hoping to get some help in determining how to initialize the multiple maps in a tab.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a simple example of putting two maps in one page. Is something like this what you needed?

HTML:

```
<div id="map_1" style="width:700px; height:500px; margin-left:80px;"></div>
<div id="map_2" style="width:700px; height:500px; margin-left:80px;"></div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 var map,map2;

  function initialize(condition) {
  // create the map

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_1"),
                                myOptions);

    map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_2"),
                                   myOptions);  
}



</script>
```